# How to create an interactive HTML table that is resizable on demand

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, graphics

I am trying to implement a plugin which enables user to drag the border of an HTML table to adjust the size of it (like below). I tried to use vanilla JavaScript but it is not perfect.

[image]

Or (as a brainstorm), maybe can I not treat it as a HTML table element but some kind of graphics on a panel and use libraries such as WebGL to make it interactive. And also implement text typing in that graphics to make it like a table. Not sure if this is feasible?